# Get console content after Javascript execute

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, console

I have an empty `<ul></ul>` on my html, which Javascript will insert a list(`<li>`) of items inside `<ul>` when the user click the button.

The problem is I want to get these new content(list of items) that was loaded by Javascript using php.

Be aware that, I'm able to get a list of content when I write it manually in html, and also able to insert it into the database, but the one loaded by Javascript, I tried var_dump and it returns NULL.  It's like it doesn't see anything in the console because originally html had no content. But after JS loaded this content, I checked my console and a new list was there but php can't see it.

Is the a way to go about it without using phantomjs? Maybe using JQuery to get this content and send it to php.

Comment: Make sure the new _li_ have a _name_ attribute assigned to them.

Comment: You mean like < li name="list"> then php I'll use $_GET["list"]? Like creating a normal form? I think I tried this before.  I've been on this problem for almost a week now.